# JSON Parsing - What are the alternate ways without URL Session task resume as it is not part of the main thread?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, nsurlsession

I am new to `Swift`. For `JSON` parsing from APIs, I found the below code.

```
guard let url = URL(string: "url path here") else {return}

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)
{
    (data, response, error) in
    guard let dataResponse = data,
        error == nil else
    {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
        return
    }
    do
    {
        //json response will be received here
        let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse, options: []) as! [String : Any]
        print(jsonResponse)


    }
    catch let parsingError
    {
        print("Error", parsingError)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Why do we need to use `task.resume()`. Is there any other way to get the `JSON` response without the above code.

Comment: Because the task is not launched by default. That's why you need to do a `resume()`. What don't you like about that?

Comment: resume is just a naming convention used by Apple. I know its confusing, should have ideally been start. But since Apple likes it. No two ways about it :)

Comment: `task.resume()` also resume tasks which are paused and since the tasks are initially suspended state i think resume is a suitable method name here.

Comment: Getting any data from any web server is a time consuming task. Main thread should never do any task that takes time to complete. Instead you offload your time consuming tasks to other threads, have a notifier (that your task is completed, like call backs) and do the final touch in Main thread (like updating the UI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do we need to use task.resume()? -

> Newly-initialized tasks begin in a suspended state, so you need to
>   call this method to start the task.

Source - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontask/1411121-resume

Is there any other way to get the jsonResponse without the above code? -

This is the basic code to get response from apis, even when you use any third parties, they internally use the same URLSession.

Comment: What if the json response needs to be populated when the view appears, as the json response here comes after the view appears

Comment: @BernyRayen views must be refreshed/set after response if received from the api, until then you can show fetching response or similar thing